# An isomorphism of higher direct images with proper support

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{q}Z$ be morphisms of schemes such that $f$ is finite and $q$, $q\circ f$ are compactifiable, which means they can be factored as an open immersion followed by a proper morphism. Let $\cal{F}$ be a torsion étale sheaf on $X$. Is it true that there is an isomorphism 
\begin{equation}
R^r(q\circ f)_!{\cal{F}} \cong R^rq_!(f_*\cal{F})
\end{equation} of higher direct images with proper support?

Let me say a bit of why I suspect this could be true. Since $f$ is finite $f_*$ is exact, and it also preserves injectives because its left adjoint $f^*$ is exact. Therefore if we take higher direct images instead, we do have an isomorphism $R^r(q\circ f)_*{\cal{F}} \cong R^rq_*(f_*\cal{F})$. This can be seen directly by the definition of derived functors with injective resolutions. But $R^rq_!$ is not a derived functor, but rather is defined as $R^rq_!:=(R^r\bar{q}_*)\circ j_!$ where $q=\bar{q}\circ j$ is a compactification and $j_!$ denotes extension by zero.

I have been able to prove the following similar result: if $X\xrightarrow{p}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$ with $g$ finite and $p,g\circ p$ compactifiable, then \begin{equation}R^r(g\circ p)_!{\cal{F}}\cong g_*R^rp_!\cal{F}.\end{equation} The key is noting that if $p=\bar{p}\circ j$ is a compactification of $p$, then $g\circ p=g\circ\bar{p}\circ j$ is a compactification of $g\circ p$ because $g$ is proper, and thus $R^r(g\circ\bar{p})_*(j_!{\cal{F}})\cong g_*R^r\bar{p}_*(j_!\cal{F})$ because $g_*$ is exact. However for my question above I'm just not able to find compactifications of $q$ and $q\circ f$ which are related to each other, or know if this even is a good approach.

Comment: The functors $f_*$ and $f_!$ are isomorphic, because $f$ is proper. So an isomorphism of the sort you want obtains from the (pseudo-)functoriality of $R(-)_!$ in (compactifiable) morphisms and the fact that $Rf_*=f_*$.

Comment: Thanks to you Oven now I think we need to ask $f$ to be étale, so that $f_!$ makes sense. Then I think my isomorphism follows from the spectral sequence $(R^rq_!)(R^sf_!)\mathcal{F}\implies {R^{r+s}(q\circ f)_!}$ ${\mathcal{F}}$, which is valid for arbitrary $f$ but, assuming I understand spectral sequences which is a very strong assumption, for $f$ finite étale reduces to the isomorphism I wanted.

Comment: Your spectral sequence reasoning is correct, but $f$ need not be étale for the isomorphism to hold. For $f$ finite one defines $f_!:=R^0f_!$, and this functor is isomorphic to $f_*$; if $q>0$ then $R^qf_!=0$.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you